# Subscription on event using java rx

Tags: java, rx-java

In java RX tutorials I see:

```
Observable<String> observable = Observable.just("Hello");
observable.subscribe(s -> result = s);

assertTrue(result.equals("Hello"));
```

or something like that:
[image]

I understand those tutorials, but, I have problems with my task. I have 2 classes: first class should play Observable role, second - Observer. How I can to make Observer to listen Observable with Java RX. Will be grateful if you post a little code example. Thanks..

Comment: Read up on [subjects](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Subject). You make those, subscribe an Observer to it, and then manually emit whenever your desired conditions are met. Is valid for rxjava2, idk about the first version.

Comment: ok, I have done this using PublishSubject, but I want to do this using Observable & Observer

Comment: I don't have much personal experience with Observers, but my guess is you either subclass one, compose one, or define an anonymous subclass, and write in the required behavior for `onSubscribe`, `onError`, `onNext`, etc. iirc I subclassed once or twice to do the same. I found Subjects overall simpler to grok; whether they're the more effective approach is unclear to me.,

Comment: There is an example just like you wanted in the 2.x Javadoc of `Observable`: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html